# Saving the Output of the Loop as a List in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a 2300 observations of 9 variables. I have a particular variable with 140 values of months. I need to subset the dataframe into multiple data frames filtering with each month.

```
    names(data)
    [1] "process_date_key" "month_key"   "percentage"         
    [4] "amount"           "sipip"       "difference"
    [7] "Rank"
```

Here the month_key is for 12 years (12*12 months = 144). I need to split this dataframe into small dataframes filtered by each month.

Can anyone, please help me do it 144 dataframes filtered by month.

Thanks,

Comment: You can check `split`

Comment: Split can do only for one value, I'm talking about 144 values into 144 different data frames.

Comment: then, make sure that you provide a small reproducible example and expected output for that example

Comment: @akrun is right, you need `split`. It will split your dataframe based on unique values, such as unique months. Have a look at the last example in the `purrr` README here:https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr.

Comment: Thanks Dom and Akrun. Let me try.

Comment: It worked. Thanks guys.